# Why does my cat (kitten) run away from me all the time?

Tags: cats, behavior, junior-pets

A cat had given birth to two kittens in our house. I used to keep milk in a bowl for them to drink. Some days later the mother cat and one kitten went away somewhere, but **one kitten remained outside our house**. It stays out at the back of our house.

I still **keep milk in a bowl for it to drink** and also **occasionally give it meat**. *It's been around a **month*** but **still the kitten runs away** *every time I try to hold her or pet her*. Even if I keep the milk in the bowl *it only comes to drink when I move a little distance away*. If I keep the minced meat in my hand it doesn't eat, if I keep it near me also it doesn't eat, but *if I throw it a little distance, it picks it up and eats*.

Why is it that the kitten hasn't become friendly yet even when I have been giving it food for more than a month?

Why is it still scared to come near me?

What can I do to gain its trust and get it to play with me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because a month really isn't a very long time. The kitten is a little over a month old and from the sounds of it has been abandoned by its mother, it's really not surprising that it's a little wary.

Keep feeding the kitten and do as much as you can to appear non-threatening. Making only nice, slow movements and trying to stay low to the ground (think how tall even a short human must seem to a newborn kitten!) is good. Speaking of the food: you say you are giving milk, is it cow's milk? If so this might not be for the best as many cats are lactose intolerant - it's less of an issue when they are still that young but you might be better off getting some proper "kitten milk" instead.

Comment: Cats can digest *goat's milk*, so that is another option.

Comment: How do I get it inside my house? It always stays outside and doesn't enter in even when the door is open.

Comment: You can try tempting it in with food or a toy. Otherwise it's probably a case of waiting for it to get sufficiently comfortable with you that you can get close enough to pick it up. If you go down that route then it would be a good idea to have some food/treats/toys ready and waiting inside so you can mollify it after the grab.

Comment: thanks a ton for the advice and one more thing I have tried practicing it with a ball outside but it hardly seems interested in playing with the ball. @motosubatsu

Comment: @MueezSiraj different cats have different toy preferences - and even the same cat can go through phases of liking/disliking certain toys. My two seem to like playing with toy balls for a week or two and then aren't bothered at all for months whereas "fishing rod" type toys are pretty much always a winner.

Comment: @motosubatsu Why has my kitten's “meow” sound reduced suddenly?
I wasn't at home from morning to evening. Morning I had given the cat some milk and left for college. When I returned in the evening, I notice that the kitten is trying to "meow" but it isn't able to make sound. It's trying hard but either the voice itself isn't coming out or just a very low volumed "meow" is coming out of is mouth. Before this it used to have a loud and sweet "meow". I am very much worried as to what has happened. please say what to do.

Comment: @mueezsiraj Outside of my expertise I'm afraid, if it appears to be in pain or distress then a vet is the best course of action

Comment: @motosubatsu, I want to show it to a vet too,it comes close only when I give it food but is still scared when I try to lift it. How do I catch it to visit the vet without me being scratched/bitten by it?

Comment: If you can get close while it is distracted (e.g by food) just scoop it up with a hand under the front shoulders. It's not going to be *happy* about it and will likely wriggle furiously but it will find it very difficult to scratch or bite you from that position. Then you need to just pop it in the cat carrier and off you go